# For Loop ended prematurely in

Tags: javascript, for-loop

[edited] include the full code for the method for your perusal.

```
 function drawHPicto(form) {
        var rowNum = form.Row.value;
        var colNum = form.Column.value;

        //The data that is to be represented on the chart
        var data = [];
        var label = [];
        var chartTitle = form.subtitle.value;

        if (colNum == 2) {
            if (rowNum == 2) {
                data.push([parseFloat(form.r1c1.value),parseFloat(form.r1c2.value)]);
                data.push([parseFloat(form.r2c1.value),parseFloat(form.r2d2.value)]);
                label.push(form.title1.value);
                label.push(form.title2.value);
            }
            else if (rowNum == 3) {
                data.push([parseFloat(form.r1c1.value),parseFloat(form.r1c2.value)]);
                data.push([parseFloat(form.r2c1.value),parseFloat(form.r2d2.value)]);
                data.push([parseFloat(form.r3c1.value),parseFloat(form.r3c2.value)]);
                label.push(form.title1.value);
                label.push(form.title2.value);
                label.push(form.title3.value);
            }
            else if (rowNum == 4) {
                data.push([parseFloat(form.r1c1.value),parseFloat(form.r1c2.value)]);
                data.push([parseFloat(form.r2c1.value),parseFloat(form.r2d2.value)]);
                data.push([parseFloat(form.r3c1.value),parseFloat(form.r3c2.value)]);
                data.push([parseFloat(form.r4c1.value),parseFloat(form.r4c2.value)]);
                label.push(form.title1.value);
                label.push(form.title2.value);
                label.push(form.title3.value);
                label.push(form.title4.value);
            }
            else if (rowNum == 5) {
                data.push([parseFloat(form.r1c1.value),parseFloat(form.r1c2.value)]);
                data.push([parseFloat(form.r2c1.value),parseFloat(form.r2d2.value)]);
                data.push([parseFloat(form.r3c1.value),parseFloat(form.r3c2.value)]);
                data.push([parseFloat(form.r4c1.value),parseFloat(form.r4c2.value)]);
                data.push([parseFloat(form.r5c1.value),parseFloat(form.r5c2.value)]);
                label.push(form.title1.value);
                label.push(form.title2.value);
                label.push(form.title3.value);
                label.push(form.title4.value);
                label.push(form.title5.value);
            }
            else if (rowNum == 6) {
                data.push([parseFloat(form.r1c1.value),parseFloat(form.r1c2.value)]);
                data.push([parseFloat(form.r2c1.value),parseFloat(form.r2d2.value)]);
                data.push([parseFloat(form.r3c1.value),parseFloat(form.r3c2.value)]);
                data.push([parseFloat(form.r4c1.value),parseFloat(form.r4c2.value)]);
                data.push([parseFloat(form.r5c1.value),parseFloat(form.r5c2.value)]);
                data.push([parseFloat(form.r6c1.value),parseFloat(form.r6c2.value)]);
                label.push(form.title1.value);
                label.push(form.title2.value);
                label.push(form.title3.value);
                label.push(form.title4.value);
                label.push(form.title5.value);
                label.push(form.title6.value);
            }
        }
        else {
            if (rowNum == 2) {
                data.push(parseFloat(form.r1c1.value));
                data.push(parseFloat(form.r2c1.value));
                label.push(form.title1.value);
                label.push(form.title2.value);
            }
            else if (rowNum == 3) {
                data.push(parseFloat(form.r1c1.value));
                data.push(parseFloat(form.r2c1.value));
                data.push(parseFloat(form.r3c1.value));
                label.push(form.title1.value);
                label.push(form.title2.value);
                label.push(form.title3.value);
            }
            else if (rowNum == 4) {
                data.push(parseFloat(form.r1c1.value));
                data.push(parseFloat(form.r2c1.value));
                data.push(parseFloat(form.r3c1.value));
                data.push(parseFloat(form.r4c1.value));
                label.push(form.title1.value);
                label.push(form.title2.value);
                label.push(form.title3.value);
                label.push(form.title4.value);
            } 
            else if (rowNum == 5) {
                data.push(parseFloat(form.r1c1.value));
                data.push(parseFloat(form.r2c1.value));
                data.push(parseFloat(form.r3c1.value));
                data.push(parseFloat(form.r4c1.value));
                data.push(parseFloat(form.r5c1.value));
                label.push(form.title1.value);
                label.push(form.title2.value);
                label.push(form.title3.value);
                label.push(form.title4.value);
                label.push(form.title5.value);
            }
            else if (rowNum == 6) {
                data.push(parseFloat(form.r1c1.value));
                data.push(parseFloat(form.r2c1.value));
                data.push(parseFloat(form.r3c1.value));
                data.push(parseFloat(form.r4c1.value));
                data.push(parseFloat(form.r5c1.value));
                data.push(parseFloat(form.r6c1.value));
                label.push(form.title1.value);
                label.push(form.title2.value);
                label.push(form.title3.value);
                label.push(form.title4.value);
                label.push(form.title5.value);
                label.push(form.title6.value);
            }
        }
        var checkNum = $('input[name=showNumberPicto]:checked').val();
        var checkLabel = $('input[name=showLabelPicto]:checked').val();

        // clear graph
        RGraph.Clear(document.getElementById('cvs'));      
        RGraph.ObjectRegistry.Clear(document.getElementById('cvs'));

        var maxValue = Math.max.apply(Math, data);
        var minValue = Math.min.apply(Math, data);

        var maxLimit = Math.floor(maxValue/4);
        var minLimit = Math.floor(minValue/4);

        // set var for javascript to validate
        setCurrentMin = minLimit;
        setCurrentMax = maxLimit;

        form.intDiv.min = minLimit;
        form.intDiv.max = maxLimit;
        if(form.intDiv.value == 1){
            form.intDiv.value = Math.floor((maxLimit+minLimit)/2);
            if (form.intDiv.value == 0){form.intDiv.value=1;};
            var divider = form.intDiv.value;
        }else{
            // check input for validation within limit
            if (form.intDiv.value>setCurrentMax) {
                form.intDiv.value = setCurrentMax;
            }else if (form.intDiv.value < setCurrentMin) {
                form.intDiv.value = setCurrentMin;
            }
            if ((maxValue/form.intDiv.value) > 7){
                form.intDiv.value = setCurrentMax;
            }
            var divider = form.intDiv.value;
            //alert(divider);
        }

        //alert (maxValue);

        //var drawCanvas = document.getElementById('cvs');
        //var context = drawCanvas.getContext('2d');
        var c=document.getElementById("cvs");
        var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
        var img = new Image();
        img.src="assets/orange.png";
        img.onload = function(){
            for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
            {
                var drawRepeat = Math.floor((data[i]/divider));
                alert(data.length);
                var reminder = Math.round(((data[i]%divider)/divider)*10);
                var getDecimal = (10-reminder)/10;
                var posY = ((i*30)+10);
                var posX = ((drawRepeat*30)+30);
                //ctx.save();
                ctx.drawImage(img,posX,posY);
                ctx.fillStyle= "#FFF";
                ctx.fillRect(posX,posY,30,getDecimal*30);

                for (var j=0;j<drawRepeat;j++){
                    var yPos = ((i*30)+10);
                    var xPos = ((j*30)+30);
                    ctx.drawImage(img,xPos,yPos);
                }

                if (checkLabel == "1") {    
                    ctx.fillStyle= "#000";
                    ctx.fillText(label[i],15,((i*30)+15))
                }else{
                    ctx.fillText("")
                }

                if (checkNum == "1") {  
                    ctx.fillStyle= "#000";
                    ctx.fillText(data[i],260,((i*30)+15))
                }else{
                    ctx.fillText("")
                }
            }
        }
}
```

So the problem lies in the for loop when img.onload occurs.

```
img.onload = function(){
                for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
                {
                    var drawRepeat = Math.floor((data[i]/divider));
                    alert(data.length);
                    var reminder = Math.round(((data[i]%divider)/divider)*10);
                    var getDecimal = (10-reminder)/10;
                    var posY = ((i*30)+10);
                    var posX = ((drawRepeat*30)+30);
                    //ctx.save();
                    ctx.drawImage(img,posX,posY);
                    ctx.fillStyle= "#FFF";
                    ctx.fillRect(posX,posY,30,getDecimal*30);

                    for (var j=0;j<drawRepeat;j++){
                        var yPos = ((i*30)+10);
                        var xPos = ((j*30)+30);
                        ctx.drawImage(img,xPos,yPos);
                    }

                    if (checkLabel == "1") {    
                        ctx.fillStyle= "#000";
                        ctx.fillText(label[i],15,((i*30)+15))
                    }else{
                        ctx.fillText("")
                    }

                    if (checkNum == "1") {  
                        ctx.fillStyle= "#000";
                        ctx.fillText(data[i],260,((i*30)+15))
                    }else{
                        ctx.fillText("")
                    }
                }
            }
```

I was using this same loop to draw images in a vertical graph manner and it worked fine. When i use this for loop to draw the horizontal graph, the for loop ended at i=0. I trace out the data.length which returns a value of 3, so the for loop should run for 3 loops but it stopped at the first loop. Anyone have a solution for this? I'm going nuts.

Comment: You might want to give us more code, as there are quite a lot of variables and functions we do not see declared, so we cannot be sure of any of their side effects.

Comment: maybe the "data" variable was changed somewhere inside the loop, I'm not familiar with canvas methods. Maybe you could store the data.length in a variable and use that variable for reference in the loop instead.

Comment: can you please provide some more information.

Comment: Do any of the `ctx` methods affect the `data` array?

Comment: The data Array is collected from a number of form inputs kinda like a table form where there can be up to 6 rows of inputs. They will be store in the data array. as for the ctx methods are drawing methods for the canvas, it doesnt affects the data array, all it does is to draw an image each of the for loops.

Comment: @KiiroSora09 I tried the storing data.length in a separate var but it didn't help. i re-edited the whole code to show the bigger picture. the data is kinda done in a hard-coded manner, sorry for the long lengths of the code.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have:

```
> if (colNum == 2) {
>     if (rowNum == 2) {
>         data.push([parseFloat(form.r1c1.value),parseFloatform.r1c2.value)]);
>         data.push([parseFloat(form.r2c1.value),parseFloat(form.r2d2.value)]);
>         ---------------------------------------------------------^
```

Likely a form control with name `r2d2` doesn't exist and causes the  incorrect result.

Comment: Must not have been the droid he was looking for.

Comment: lolx. kinda did that on purpose :P but the input field name is correct. there is an input with the name called r2d2.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (checkLabel == "1") {    
                    ctx.fillStyle= "#000";
                    ctx.fillText(label[i],15,((i*30)+15))
                }else{
                    ctx.fillText("",15,((i*30)+15))
                }
```

Manage to find where the problem is, previously in the else statement I set ctx.fillText(""); without the x and y coordinates, apparently that stopped the loop.